# Ninject InRequestScope sometimes seems to return a wrong instance

Tags: caching, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, ninject, requestscope

I am developing an `MVC 5 application` that uses `Ninject` to handle dependency injection. The application defines a `SecurityService` that provided various information about current logged user. I am using Windows Authentication.

Ok, let's dive into the code.

**NinjectWebCommon.cs**

```
    private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
    private static KernelBase kernel;

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the application
    /// </summary>
    public static void Start() 
    {
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
        bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the application.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Stop()
    {
        bootstrapper.ShutDown();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        kernel = new StandardKernel();
        try
        {
            kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
            kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

            RegisterServices(kernel);
            return kernel;
        }
        catch
        {
            kernel.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Load your modules or register your services here!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<ISecurityService>().To<SecurityService>().InRequestScope();

        // custom bindings are defined here
    }

    public static void PerformInjectionOn(object instance)
    {
        kernel.Inject(instance);
    }
```

Please, notice `kernel.Bind<ISecurityService>().To<SecurityService>().InRequestScope();` for security binding definition.

**SecurityService.cs**

```
    private AppUser _CurrentUser = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// gets logged user data, based on current identity username (Sam account name)
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>AppUser object if windows identity maps to an existing active user. Otherwise null</returns>
    public AppUser GetLoggedUserData()
    {
        lock(lockObj)
        {
            String currUsername = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

            // comparison between current user name and actually authenticated user is needed since some requests end with different values!
            if (_CurrentUser == null || !_CurrentUser.Username.Equals(currUsername))
            {
                _CurrentUser = _ScopedDataAccess.AppUserRepository.AllNoTracking
                    // some includes
                    .SingleOrDefault(u => u.IsEnabled && u.Username.Equals(currUsername));

                if (_CurrentUser == null)
                {
                    logger.LogEx(LogLevel.Info, "GetLoggedUserData -  user {0} authentication failed", currUsername);
                    return null;
                }
            }

            return _CurrentUser;
        }
    }
```

My problem is that, even if `SecurityService` is instantiated per request, sometimes I receive an instance where `_CurrentUser.Username` is different from `currUsername` (i.e. both are valid A/D users with which I perform the test).

Current workaround is to have `!_CurrentUser.Username.Equals(currUsername)` to invalidate cached user instance, if request authenticated user is different from cached one, but I would like to know what is happening.

Just out of curiosity, I have checked `InThreadScope` and had the same problem, but I think this can be explained by the fact that the thread pool used by IIS may provide the same thread for another request.

**Does anyone know why InRequestScope behaves like this?**

Thanks.

**[edit]**

Call stack when current user is different from cached one:

> ProjectName.Models.dll!ProjectName.Models.SecurityService.GetLoggedUserData() Line 54   C#
>       ProjectName.Models.dll!ProjectName.Models.SecurityService.GetAndCheckUserData() Line 76 C#
>       ProjectName.Models.dll!ProjectName.Models.SecurityService.IsAdmin.get() Line 98 C#
>       ProjectName.Models.dll!ProjectName.Models.EntitiesCache.ProjectStatuses.get() Line 51   C#
>       ProjectName.Services.dll!ProjectName.Services.ProjectService.CreateSelectorsDomain() Line 253   C#
>       ProjectName.Services.dll!ProjectName.Services.ProjectService.ProjectService(ProjectName.Models.ISecurityService securityService, ProjectName.Models.IEntitiesCache entitiesCache, ProjectName.Models.IScopedDataAccess dataAccess, ProjectName.Services.IProjectTemplateService projectTemplateService) Line 33 C#
>       [External Code] 
>       ProjectName.Web.dll!ProjectName.Web.NinjectWebCommon.PerformInjectionOn(object instance) Line 93    C#
>       ProjectName.Web.dll!ProjectName.Web.BaseController.BaseController() Line 21 C#
>       [External Code]

The logic in all steps in synchronous (no `async`, `await`, no `Tasks`)

Comment: Is there async/await anywhere in the call stack?

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit - I have added the call stack and also checked all the steps within my code for async behavior. Thanks.